# Is there software available for two-factor, biometric authentication to the OS?

Tags: authentication, multi-factor, biometrics

Many fingerprint readers and other biometric authentication devices come with software for single-factor authentication to the OS.  Is there any third-party software (F/OSS or otherwise) available for making OS authentication a two-factor process, such as by requiring both a fingerprint *and* a passcode?